# LA Kings' "That 70's line"

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, nhl

I was watching the Kings vs Canucks last night and the commentators kept referring to Jeff Carter's line as the "70's line". What is the reason behind this?

Also how long has it been called that? I never heard anyone call Carter's line that name in any of the past few seasons.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was called the "70's line" because of the jersey numbers

Jeff Carter is 77
Tyler Tiffoli is 73
Tanner Pearson is 70

Comment: More specifically, it's called "that 70's line" (and not "the 70's line" or just "70's line") as a reference to [That '70s Show](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0165598/), a popular American sitcom from the late 1990s.